# why doesn't list retain it's value?

Tags: python

From the code below, why doesn't the list (z) retain it's value before appending another numpy array (r) to it? (after z becomes non-empty, z seems to get r value even before appending r to it) How do you make it retain value? For example, the end result should be z =

```
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 2.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [0. 0. 4.]
 [0. 0. 5.]]
```

code:

```
    import numpy as np
    r = np.zeros(3)
    z=[]
    for i in range (1,6):
      r[2] = i
      print("r")
      print(r)
      print("z before appending r")
      print(z)
      z.append(r)
      print("z after appending r")
      print(z)
    z=np.array(z)
    print("z after numpy'd")
    print(z)
```

run result:

```
r
[0. 0. 1.]
z before appending r
[]
z after appending r
[array([0., 0., 1.])]
r
[0. 0. 2.]
z before appending r
[array([0., 0., 2.])]
z after appending r
[array([0., 0., 2.]), array([0., 0., 2.])]
r
[0. 0. 3.]
z before appending r
[array([0., 0., 3.]), array([0., 0., 3.])]
z after appending r
[array([0., 0., 3.]), array([0., 0., 3.]), array([0., 0., 3.])]
r
[0. 0. 4.]
z before appending r
[array([0., 0., 4.]), array([0., 0., 4.]), array([0., 0., 4.])]
z after appending r
[array([0., 0., 4.]), array([0., 0., 4.]), array([0., 0., 4.]), array([0., 0., 4.])]
r
[0. 0. 5.]
z before appending r
[array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.])]
z after appending r
[array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.]), array([0., 0., 5.])]
z after numpy'd
[[0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is `z.append(r)` add the same object which is pointed by `r` into `z`, so `z` is a list of five **same** objects in the end.

Change that statement to `z.append(np.array(r))` and have another try.

Comment: Thank you! That works!! 
In python, do I pretty much assume when passing anything other than immutable, it will be passed by reference? 
Since np.array is mutable, why does it work/fix the problem in this case?

Comment: You welcome. That works as `z.append(np.array(r))` raises a new object which is initialized using `r`, and adds this new object into `z`. For **by reference**, maybe you would like to have a look on following page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

You are appending a new row at each iteration, accordingly you should do z[i-1, 2] = i